# MvvmCross localization: switch at runtime

Tags: windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is there a way to change the current language to another one at runtime ?

For example: be able to switch when a button is clicked or when starting the app, get the user language and switch.

How to tell the plugin to check the user language at startup ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the current language to another one at runtime ?

yes, call `builder.LoadResources(whichLanguage)` on your [MvxTextProviderBuilder.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Plugins/JsonLocalisation/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.JsonLocalisation/MvxTextProviderBuilder.cs)

> For example: be able to switch when a button is clicked

The UI framework isn't really setup to perform switching live. When you switch between languages then the new JSON resource files will all be loaded OK - but existing displayed text will not be updated. This is a bit like most mobile operating systems - if you want to switch language you often need to reboot!

If you wanted to add dynamic switching then you'd have to find a way to tell the UI to completely refresh all text - I suspect this wouldn't be hard to do, but it might require some manual coding on every page/View which has already been created and displayed :/

> or when starting the app, get the user language and switch.

This is a much more straight-forward way to do i18n. It's normally OK because MvvmCross mainly targets phones - and phones are normally single user devices which don't switch languages very often.

- You could, for example, use some variable (e.g. `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`) to work out the best language to display.
- Or you detect on load whether the user has picked a language yet - if they have, then show `HomeViewModel` - if they haven't then show a `LanguagePickerViewModel` - this is what we did in StarWarsKinect - the `StartNavigationObject` is a perfect place for this sort of logic!

[image: SWK Language Pick]

> How to tell the plugin to check the user language at startup ?

Currently, you'll have to code this logic as part of your app startup.

I'd definitely be open to providing an improved plugin on this - perhaps with a demo!

---

If you are looking at i18n, then one alternative implementation to consider is Vernacular - the team at Rdio have a very good offering for Mono and MS platforms - https://github.com/rdio/vernacular

Comment: I added language to BaseConferenceApp constructor which is the sample for localization, then my Android Setup.cs CreateApp  return new NoSplashScreenConferenceApp(Java.Util.Locale.Default.Language); so the default language is used.

Comment: Your implementation seems to do the job perfectly, I will not consider another framework for now and follow your recommandations.

Comment: For now, it is not possible to do the same as the end of the post with MvvmCross Localisation plugin without reloading: http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/localize-a-windows-phone-7-application/

Comment: If you use databinding for your text you could probably do something with a little hacking... e.g. if using binding like `local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'TextSource','Converter':'Language','ConverterParameter':'SQLBitsXApp'}}"` from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Resources/Layout/Page_About.axml then you could just RaisePropertyChanged(() => TextSource) on all existing ViewModels... there would be some plumbing needed for this...

Comment: any updates on this? trying to figure out the best way to load a language on a login screen. I could use a screen on first launch , but it would rather have the option to change it on a login screen