# Localising text in MvvmCross ViewModels

Tags: localization, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I'd like to get all my localised text from the ViewModels (as it's often dynamic), and I was wondering how you'd use a converter to get the text from the json files used for localisation. For instance, in the code below, I'd like LocalisedString to use the converter which I currently use in my Views in the bindings for static text -

```
public string MyText // used in the binding in the View
{
    get
    {
        string exclamation;

        if (MyValue <= 3.3)
        {
            exclamation = LocalisedString("Rubbish!");
        }
        else if (OverallScore > 3.3 && OverallScore <= 6.6)
        {
            exclamation = LocalisedString("Good!");
        }
        else
        {
            exclamation = LocalisedString("Excellent!");
        }

        return exclamation;
    }
}
```

Currently using version 1 of MvvmCross.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note:** this answer is about vNext - it should be fairly easy to port back to master... The differences in the area aren't that big.

---

There is a text localisation mechanism built into MvvmCross.

The only public sample that uses it is the Conference Sample.

---

This sample includes shared and ViewModel specific Json files - [see](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/OldSamples/CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.WP7/ConfResources/Text)

These Json files each contain simple key-value pairs like:

```
{
"Title":"SQLBits X",
"Welcome":"Welcome",
"Sessions":"Sessions",
"Sponsors":"Sponsors",
"Tweets":"Tweets",
"Favorites":"Favorites"
}
```

They are linked in to Droid, Touch and WP as content or assets... all accessed by the platform using the ResourceLoader plugin.

---

To use these JSON files at runtime, the core project loads them up in the [TextProviderBuilder](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.Core/ApplicationObjects/TextProviderBuilder.cs):

```
    protected override IDictionary<string, string> ResourceFiles
    {
        get
        {
            var dictionary = this.GetType()
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
                .Where(t => !t.Name.StartsWith("Base"))
                .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.Name);

            dictionary[Constants.Shared] = Constants.Shared;
            return dictionary;
        }
    }
```

You could obviously easily load other JSON files here if you wanted to. It's not uncommon for some of my apps to have:

- a file for errors
- a file for general shared statements
- a file for specific components
- a file per ViewModel

While others have:

- just one big file!

Internationalisation - when it is done - is done by loading a different set of JSON files. Typically what is done is you load the default set first, then you load incremental overrides - so you might load English as default, Cat as an override and Cat-Lol as a further refinement.

For some discussions on this see:

- [MvvmCross localization: switch at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455635/mvvmcross-localization-switch-at-runtime)
- and some future enhancements - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/55

---

Assuming you have one shared file and one file per ViewModel, then to provide runtime access to the text values from the JSON, the BaseViewModel presents 2 properties:

```
    public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource
    {
        get { return new MvxLanguageBinder(Constants.GeneralNamespace, GetType().Name); }
    }

    public IMvxLanguageBinder SharedTextSource
    {
        get { return new MvxLanguageBinder(Constants.GeneralNamespace, Constants.Shared); }
    }
```

These properties are used in data binding using:

- Path specifying whether to use SharedTextSource or TextSource
- MvxLanguageBinderConverter as the Converter
- the text key as the ConverterParameter

For example, in Droid this is :

```
<TextView
  style="@style/AboutPageBodyText"
  local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'TextSource','Converter':'Language','ConverterParameter':'Title'}}"
  />
```

Although in modern 'Swiss' binding this would be written as:

```
<TextView
  style="@style/AboutPageBodyText"
  local:MvxBind="Text TextSource, Converter=Language, ConverterParameter='Title'"
  />
```

Any code which wishes to use the Text can also do it - see for example how the TimeAgo text is created from resource strings in [TimeAgoConverter.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.Core/Converters/TimeAgoConverter.cs)  which uses resource strings like:

```
{
"TimeAgo.JustNow":"just now",
"TimeAgo.SecondsAgo":"{0}s ago",
"TimeAgo.MinutesAgo":"{0}m ago",
"TimeAgo.HoursAgo":"{0}h ago",
"TimeAgo.DaysAgo":"{0}d ago",
"TimeAgo.Never":"never"
}
```

The code for this is effectively:

```
 var valueToFormat = 42;
 var whichFormat = "TimeAgo.DaysAgo";

 var textProvider = this.GetService<IMvxTextProvider>();
 var format = textProvider.GetText(Constants.GeneralNamespace, Constants.Shared, whichFormat);

 return string.Format(format, valueToFormat)
```

---

The language Binder and the ValueConverter are really very simple code

- [MvxLanguageBinder.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localisation/MvxLanguageBinder.cs)
- [MvxLanguageBinderConverter.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localisation/Converters/MvxLanguageBinderConverter.cs)

So feel free to build something more sophisticated for your app if you need it.

---

Other cross-platform text localisation techniques are available - I myself would particularly like to try Vernacular one day - https://github.com/rdio/vernacular

Comment: just adding another linked topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471994/mvvmcross-localization-get-text-from-dynamic-value

Comment: Many thanks for this - I'll be trying over the next few days to sort it out - I'll get back with my results.

Comment: Great - I've got it all working nicely now, as you say, pretty simple in the end

Comment: Fab - if there's anything you think is missing or misleading, feel free to blog about it or to contribute something to the wiki or to comments on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/55 or https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/53 or https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/63 :)

Comment: Stuart did you ever try Vernacular?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be returning enums instead of strings and handle the localization in the views.

Comment: Because it's a cross-platform app (iPhone, Android & Win) we're trying to avoid doing too much in the Views

Comment: Going to have to agree to disagree. In my view localization is strictly a View problem as each platform handles it differently and has different guidance for each. Handling it at the ViewModel level ties your View to your ViewModel, which is the problem MVVM tries to avoid.

Comment: I'd assumed that binding from the View to VM properties sort of ties you in anyway...